# How to create a TYPE (UDT) in cassandra using the type name cast. Is it possible to create cast as a type because it is a function?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra

when creating TYPE in cassandra cli eg: cqlsh: create type cast (name text, role text) i am getting error

> " line 1:16 mismatched input '(' expecting '.' (create type
>   cast[(]...) "

Actually i am using spring boot for creating TYPE in
cassandra-DB. I have tried manually in cassandra cli as well as in spring boot. Both are not working spring boot is throwing exception at the time running the application.

Please refer this link for more clarity ?

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/functions.html

please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Every object in Cassandra need to be defined in some keyspace. You either need to specify the full type name in form of `keyspace.name`, or execute `use keyspace;` before executing this command.

Looks like a bug in Cassandra (feel free to file a JIRA), if you really need to use that name, you can try to specify it as:

```
create type test."cast"(...
```

but in this case, the name of the type will be case sensitive, and you'll need always specify it in double quotes.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like an error in Cassandra, although `cast` isn't listed as reserved keyword... See updated answer